# Regarding licensing of FCK Editor

Tags: fckeditor

What is the difference between FCK Editor and CK Editor? 
Is there any restriction on using FCK Editor v2.6.3 for commercial use?

Answer (score 0):

Did you search on the web?

According to [its web page](http://drupal.org/project/fckeditor) FCK editor is **obsolete** and no more maintained.

PS. I never heard if FCK editor before reading your question, but I have the habits of searching a few minutes on the web before asking.

Comment: From the web, i could found that FCK Editor is actually the old version of CK Editor. The FCK Editor version which we are using is currently satisfying our requirements. So we need to continue with that. I just need to clarify whether i can use the FCK Editor for commercial applications.